# How exchange files securely?

Tags: file, share, file-sharing, truecrypt, file-security

I need some software that will allow securely file exchange. Preferable for free =) But it's not principally. For example TrueCrypt is very hard for my task. I would like to encrypt (for example) my file (fast) and send to adddress who can decrypt file (fast too) by this program. Who knows about such soft?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't ask us to recommend a tool or software library. This is considered off-topic. For more information, see [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic)

Comment: The question is not clear. For transmission over the Internet use https, the encryption is done seamlessly.

Comment: OK, sorry. What if I can't use https or share files not via Internet...

Comment: I need just tool, not secure data link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot such tools. If you don't want TrueCrypt, try for example

- AxCrypt

**AxCrypt** by Axantum. It's free, but provide only AES-128 (not too hard), this tools may be suitable for you because it provides portable version, what is more encrypting and decrypting tools are two different programms (AxCrypt2Go and AxDecrypt respectively). Accessible by [AxCrypt](https://www.axcrypt.net/)

- SafeBox

Another one is **SafeBox**. Light tool, support asymmetric and symmetric enctryption. Has clear inteface and detailed instructions on site. This tool has more strong encryption algorythm. Files can be shared via any channel that supports text or wrapped up in a container. Accessible by [SafeBox](https://sfbox.org/)